# Find and sketch the transfer function

Tags: diodes, transfer-function

This is the original circuit, we assume Vdo=0.7V, this is for when either of the diodes are on.
[image: Circuit Schematic]

We know both diodes cannot both be off because then no current would flow in the circuit. I become stumped when only one of the diodes is on, how do I find Vo?

[image]

Comment: Your diagrams are rather haphazard and confusing to me.  There is no definition of what the endpoints are (V1 and V0?) and to what (voltages?) they can be connected. *"We know both diodes cannot both be off because then no current would flow in the circuit. "* I can see a situation in which both diodes are off and there IS a current flowing through R1 and R2.(Assuming ideal diodes with a Vd of 0.7V)

Comment: @Oldfart I think they're Vi and Vo, as in input and output.

Comment: the first diagram shows both Vi and Vo as being at ground potential

Comment: `simpify` and `normalize` the circuit before you do any calculations

Comment: I could think of a 3D graph where Vi and Vo change between e.g. -4V..+4V forming the X and Y axis and the Z-axis is the current flowing somewhere. But that seems a bit extreme.

Comment: @Oldfart if both diodes are off, Id1 and Id2 (the currents through the diodes) are 0. What would the current in the circuit would therefore be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit simplifies to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQtH2Dm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does this help with your analysis?

Comment: Indeed it does. I calculate Vo=3.7V when D2 is off and D1 is on. Vo=2.3V when D2 is on and D1 is off. I also find the diodes can neither be both on or both off.

Comment: They can't be both on, but they can be both off if Vo is within +/-0.7V of +3V.

Comment: @Hector Hence my remark of: *" I can see a situation..."*

Answer (score 0):

It might be good practice to re-visualize circuits, or re-draw them in different forms to help with circuit solutions.
  For example, the circuit below is electrically equivalent to yours. **Vin** is a voltage source...I imagine it as a triangle wave so that it "sweeps" input voltage linearly up & down:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYf4gv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is the purpose of V1? I did not have that in my original circuit, only Vin

Comment: **V1** is equivalent to your +3V DC. Your circuit, this circuit and @DaveTweed circuit are electrically equivalent.